# change default landing page at clicking on "create" button while creating content through document library action alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

change default landing page at clicking on "create"  button while creating content through document library action  alfresco

While  creating any content  ,  it lands to the  " view details "  page of the created content  in alfresco share . As per requirement it  needs  to land to the  site document library.

Comment: It looks like you've cross-posted this question to the Alfresco discussion forums: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/214682-change-default-landing-page-at-clicking-on-create-button-while-creating-content-through-document-library-action-alfresco where it has been answered.

Comment: thanks a lot Dave Draper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override JS create-content-mgr.js. 
Place at "web/components/create-content/" with the required logic.